# Is there a word for the opposite of an intended effect?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a word in English connected to a process resulting in not just an unexpected outcome, but the direct opposite of its intended effect? Like feeling more tired after waking up? Or feeling dirtier after washing your hands (because the bathroom isn't clean)?

Example Sentence:

> "I got 8 hours of sleep but I'm more tired than when I went to sleep.
>   That's so _____."

Comment: Can you add the customary example sentence required for an SWR?

Comment: @alwayslearning "I got 8 hours of sleep but I'm more tired than when I went to sleep. That's so _____." Does that work?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the example sentence mentioned in your comment. Feel free to undo/refine the edit.

Comment: I'm not answering because it's not actually anything like an opposite of 'intended effect', but idiomatically the end of that sentence is: 'That's so typical[ of me]!' (It usually of course *isn't* typical, but conveys annoyance at oneself for doing daft things.)

Comment: "Unexpected" does describe "the direct opposite of an intended effect"

Comment: Maybe even oxymoronous?

Comment: Unexpected could be the opposite, but could also be something completely different. If I push a chair and the chair moves towards me instead of away, that's opposite of expectation. If the chair transforms into an albatross and flies around the room, that's unexpected, but not opposite of expectation.

Comment: Counter (or contrary) to expectations.

Comment: From the question title I thought you were looking for a verb, and I thought, **backfire**. But that's not the kind of word you were looking for apparently.

Comment: @Cruncher - The word you're thinking of is *oxymoronic*.

Comment: Not to name events but a country might go in to stabilize a region and what happens is even nastier people come into power and things get worse.

Comment: @m69 You have 101 reputation; you should be able to post an answer now.

Answer (score 34):

Ironically, I think the word ironically could be used here literally.

**"I got 8 hours of sleep but I'm more tired than when I went to sleep. That's so ironic."**

I prefer a different sentence though.

**Ironically, I woke up less rested than when I went to sleep.**

Comment: I really wasn't sure (still am not) if I was looking for a noun or an adjective, so it's not the best of example sentences...

Comment: When the word you wish to use is found, often the sentence, paragraph and more must be adjusted.

Comment: @miltonaut Just as a point, while a thing can be ironic (adjective), you could also use 'irony', the noun form.  E.g. "The irony is that I woke up less rested than when I went to sleep."

Answer (score 25):

> **counterproductive**.
>   adjective 
>   ​
>   having an effect that is opposite to the one intended or wanted:
>   *Improved safety measures in cars can be counterproductive as they encourage people to drive faster*.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/counterproductive

Answer (score 25):

Based on the example sentence, a suitable word is ***counterintuitive***.

> "I got 8 hours of sleep but I'm more tired than when I went to sleep.
>   That's so ***counterintuitive***."

ODO:

> **[counterintuitive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/counterintuitive)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Contrary to intuition or to common-sense expectation (but often
>   nevertheless true)
>
> ‘The trick is again counter-intuitive: instead of accelerating rapidly
>   when traffic gets going, travel more slowly.’

Comment: Only a  rule can be counterintuitive, not an individual experience.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, can you please point me to a resource which says only a rule can be counterintuitive? Also, please check the other examples at the ODO entry cited/linked.

Comment: I up voted this answer, but I think a few others are actually just as good. I don't think there is a single word answer for this situation, I think there are many adjectives that would work. A thesaurus would be most applicable.

Comment: @michael.hor257k really? That's kind of counter intuitive. Especially because many rules themselves aren't necessarily intuitive. Hence why they're rules.

Answer (score 23):

I would say that in your specific example ***[paradoxical](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paradoxical)*** fits best.

> paradoxical
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> Seemingly absurd or self-contradictory.
>
> ‘by glorifying the acts of violence they achieve the paradoxical effect of making them trivial’

Comment: "That's so paradoxical", to use the ops example.  youth is wasted on the young. "i was so much older then, i'm younger than that now" (Dylan).  the sun was so hot i froze to death  etc.

Comment: In drugs in mean opposite effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxical_reaction

Answer (score 17):

You can say it **backfired** on you.

[Definition from OED:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/backfire)

> **backfire**
>
> verb
>
> **1**: (of a vehicle or its engine) undergo a mistimed explosion in the cylinder or exhaust.
>
> *‘a car backfired in the road and shoppers ducked instinctively’*
>
> **2**: (of a plan or action) have an opposite and undesirable effect to what was intended.
>
> *‘overzealous publicity backfired on her’*

"I got 8 hours of sleep but I'm more tired than when I went to sleep. That **backfired** on me."

Answer (score 6):

A common word which means the opposite or inverse of what is expected is [contrary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contrary). It's often used in phrases like "on the contrary" or "to the contrary" when talking about the direct opposite of a desired effect.

Similar words include [contradictory](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contradictory) and [antithetical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antithetical). Contradictory tends to have connotations of evidence or information, as in contradictory statements, and antithetical is more often associated with beliefs or principles than expectations or outcomes. Contrary is more likely to be associated with an outcome or result.

"I expected gas prices to rise on the announcement of the embargo, but quite the contrary, they actually dropped."

It could be used in the example sentence like so... 
"I got 8 hours of sleep but I'm more tired than when I went to sleep. That's so contrary."

and this would be understandable by most people, but would sound archaic or off. It would  more commonly used in a phrase like "contrary to expectation."

A more likely example would be something like this: 
"I got 8 hours of sleep, but I don't feel rested. On the contrary, I feel more tired than when I went to sleep."

Answer (score 4):

The word you're looking for is ***blowback***:

> [**blowback**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blowback) an unforeseen and unwanted effect, result, or set of
>   repercussions.
>
> [**blowback**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowback_(intelligence)) the unintended consequences, the unwanted
>   (side-)effects or suffered repercussions of a covert operation that
>   fall back on those responsible for the aforementioned operations.

Although the term is generally used to refer to politics and the activities of secret agencies, it can mnemonically be used in other contexts, and it is an apt phrase for what you describe.

Comment: This word indicates unexpected or surprising consequences, but not that they are actually the opposite of the intention. The side-effects could be tangential and still be blowback.

Comment: I think of blowback more a resistance.

Answer (score 3):

> Feeling dirtier and more tired after taking a shower and getting 8
>   hours of sleep defies logic.
>     In a word, it’s downright
>   [“logic-defying.”](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/defying)

---

> Definition of '-defying'   (from *Collins English Dictionary*)
>   adjective
>   (in combination)
>   at odds or in contradiction with the thing specified
>    death-defying
>   logic-defying
>   an imposing and
>   logic-defying structure

Answer (score 3):

How about **boomerang**? It doesn't capture your example sentence, but it does get at an action having the opposite of the desired effect.

OD:

> [**boomerang**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/boomerang): (of a plan or action) recoil on the originator.

OD provides numerous supporting examples.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply say **"That doesn't make sense."** Like in "I had a huge lunch but felt even hungrier than before. That didn't make any sense". Or "I went out of my way to accommodate him but he still didn't have a single nice word. It just didn't make sense."

Answer (score 3):

A **side-effect** of anti-depressants can be additional depression.

[**Side-effect**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/side--effect) noun

> any effect of a drug, chemical, or other medicine that is in addition to its intended effect, especially an effect that is harmful or unpleasant.

Comment: I find it fascinating that the legal blurbs on ads for anti-depressants include such side effects as "increased thoughts of suicide". To me, that's pretty much a deal-breaker right there. If I'm depressed, the last thing I need is to make me think about suicide.

Comment: @MontyHarder To be honest, my answer was added somewhat in jest. Depression is a severely complicated issue and everyone's chemical balance is different. One medication can work miracles for one person yet wreak havoc on another; hence why there are countless brands to choose from. It is comparable to how a certain foods are tasty to one person yet a different person is repulsed by the flavor.

Comment: And yet I've never seen an ad for presumably-tasty food with a disclaimer "side effects may include nausea, dry heaves, and/or projectile vomiting" even though I'm pretty sure those have been among my reactions to alleged "foods" I've eaten.  Just a matter of time until the lawyers get around to it, I suppose.

Comment: I don't think this really fits the example situations. Too medicine-oriented (although it can be used in other ways: One side effect of barbed wire was the end of cattle drives). It doesn't directly reflect the "opposite-ness" that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobra_effect

> The cobra effect occurs when an attempted solution to a problem
>   actually makes the problem worse.
>
> The term cobra effect stems from an anecdote set at the time of
>   British rule of colonial India. The British government was concerned
>   about the number of venomous cobra snakes in Delhi.[3] The government
>   therefore offered a bounty for every dead cobra. Initially this was a
>   successful strategy as large numbers of snakes were killed for the
>   reward. Eventually, however, enterprising people began to breed cobras
>   for the income. When the government became aware of this, the reward
>   program was scrapped, causing the cobra breeders to set the
>   now-worthless snakes free. As a result, the wild cobra population
>   further increased. The apparent solution for the problem made the
>   situation even worse.

Answer (score 0):

### Illogical

I got 8 hours of sleep but I'm more tired than when I went to sleep. That's so illogical.